# Trivial query with if statements

Tags: c, if-statement

How to achieve this simple logic?

```
void IRQHandler(void)
{
   if(update_variable == 0)
    {
        if(CONDITION1)
         {

            /* MORE CODE */
            update_variable = 1;
          }
    } /* Here i want to exit the loop */

    if(update_variable == 1) /* execute in next loop */
     { 
         if(CONDITION1)
          {
            /* MORE CODE */ 
            /*UPDATE SOME ARRAY */ 
            update_variable = 0; /* reset variable for next loop */
          } 
      }
  }
```

Essentially, I want to check for the same CONDITION1 over two consecutive interrupts. For 1st interrupt, I want to update the variable value to 1 and exit the loop (precisely do not execute the following if condition).  As I see, I cannot use break condition with "if"! I am struck here for a while! Please help me!

Comment: `if` is a condition, not a loop that you can `break` out of !

Comment: Use a static variable with a switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mentioning loops and you are not using any.

As from what I understand about your question, and you do not want to enter the second condition EVER, just use an `else`condition.

```
void IRQHandler(void)
{
   if(update_variable == 0)
    {
        if(CONDITION1)
         {

            /* MORE CODE */
            update_variable = 1;
          }
    } /* Here i want to exit the loop */

    else if(update_variable == 1) /* execute in next loop */
     { 
         if(CONDITION1)
          {
            /* MORE CODE */ 
            /*UPDATE SOME ARRAY */ 
            update_variable = 0; /* reset variable for next loop */
          } 
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no **loop** in your code, just a bunch of selection statements using `if` condition.

In this case, seeing this as a function body, if you want execution not to continue to the rest part, you can always `return ;` from the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(update_variable == 0)
    {
        if(CONDITION1)
         {
            /* MORE CODE */
            update_variable = 1;
          }
         return;
    } /* Here i want to exit the loop */
```

It's not a loop, so there's nothing to `break` from. Use `return` to exit the function.

In this case it's better to go for M.K's answer and use `else` but return is always an option to exit a function at any place in the code. It can be very useful if you want to exit from a lot of nested if statements.

Example:

```
if(cond1) {
   <code>
   if(cond2) {
      <code>
      if(cond3) {
         <code>
         if(cond4) {
             return;
         }
      <code>
      }
   <code>
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(CONDITION1)
{
   if(update_variable == 0)
   {
         /* MORE CODE */
          update_variable = 1;
   } 
   else if(update_variable == 1)
   {
         /*Update Some Array*/
         /* MORE CODE */
          update_variable == 0;
   }
}
```

Just use an `else` condition and it would be better if you check `CONDITION1` initially.

Comment: You can change the if else statement into a single line statement like : `update_variable = 0 ? 1 : 0`, And here what is **CONDITION1**?